# Is it possible to classify patches of the image of the same object, but with different areas with CNN?

Tags: python, opencv, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have two pictures of a printed object, the first has a printed area of 2.5x2.5 cm^2, and the second is the same object, but the printed area is 5.0x5.0 cm^2. After separating the object from the background and equalizing the histogram of both pictures, I am trying to use small patches (64x64) in a deep learning approach (CNN) to understanding their patterns and classify them. I am trying to use 64x64 patches from the 2.5x2.5cm^2 printed objects to train a deep learning classifier and test them with patches from 5.0x5.0cm^2 objects. The digital images of both objects have approximately the same resolution, as it is defined from the object extractor. Here are examples of the 64x64 patches used to train and test the CNN binary classifier.

[image]
64x64 patch of a 2.5x2.5cm^2 object

[image]

64x64 patch of a 5x5cm^2 object

The classes I want to predict are the following:

[image: Negative Class]

Negative Class (printed for the first time)

[image: Positive Class]

Positive class (copied and reprinted)

What I found out:

1. Patches from 2.5x2.5cm^2 objects are easily classified if the CNN is trained with patches from the same size (area) objects
2. If the CNN is trained with 64x64 patches from 2.5x2.5cm^2 objects and tested with 64x64 patches from 5x5cm^2 objects, the predictions are just for one class (50% accuracy).
3. Some multiscale and multiple resolution descriptors work perfectly in this scenario, such as using Bag of Visual Words
4. Other baseline CNNs also fail in this scenario, such as Mobilenet, Densenet and Resnet
5. I tried to include zooms in my data augmentation procedure (like suggested by one answer). It did not work either :-(

This is the keras model I have tried so far

```
model = Sequential()

# GROUP1
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))


# GROUP2
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.9, epsilon=0.001))

# GROUP3
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.9, epsilon=0.001))

# GROUP4
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.9, epsilon=0.001))

# GROUP5
model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.9, epsilon=0.001))

# GROUP6
model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.9, epsilon=0.001))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

return model
```

and here is the data augmentation I am using

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
            width_shift_range=0.2,
            height_shift_range=0.2,
            horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip=True,
        zoom_range=0.2,
            fill_mode='nearest')


    datagen.fit(x_train)
    datagen.fit(x_validation)

    # Fit the model on the batches generated by datagen.flow().
    model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
                        steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] // batch_size,
                        validation_data=datagen.flow(x_validation, y_validation, batch_size=batch_size),
                        epochs=nb_epoch, verbose=1, max_q_size=100,
                        validation_steps=x_validation.shape[0]//batch_size,
                        callbacks=[lr_reducer, early_stopper, csv_logger, model_checkpoint])
```

So, is there any solution to increase the accuracy in this very difficult scenario for CNNs? I mean, CNN learns features from data and, as you can see, the training and testing data from the same class are different. So, is that possible for me to perform any data augmentation or CNN operation (my CNN has no dropouts and no pooling, as you can see above) that could minimize or simulate the testing data in the training data?

Comment: Maybe enlarge the inputs will help.

Comment: I tried to include zoom in my data augmentation procedure and it didn't help. What do you mean by enlarging the inputs? different patch sizes?

Comment: What zoom range are you using?

Comment: @spadarian 0.2 range (Please check my edit)

Comment: So what is your final goal? Predict at any zoom level?
You need to train your CNN depending on what you want to achieve...

Comment: Probably yes (predicting at any zoom level, or at least the levels I have shown so far). Do you believe that increasing the zoom range I'll get satisfactory results? 0.2 range did not work :-(

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to predict at multiple zoom levels, you need to train the CNN with multiple zoom levels...
I think the current augmentation is generating samples which are not what you want. For example, this is one of the images that could be generated when zoom=1.2:

[image: augmented_image]

The simplest solution would be to use a generator like this when training with the 5x5cm^2 patches:

```
ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True,
                   vertical_flip=True,
                   zoom_range=[0.5, 1])
```

In that case, when zoom=0.5 you will get an image like this:

[image]

which is more or less equivalent to a 2.5x2.5cm^2 image.

If you have to train it using the 2.5x2.5 patches try:

```
ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True,
                   vertical_flip=True,
                   zoom_range=[1, 2],
                   fill_mode='constant',
                   cval=0)
```

which generate images like this one:

[image]

With enough samples and epochs, the CNN should be able to learn that the padding zeros can be ignored.

Comment: I must train with 2.5x2.5 patches. How can I do that? just inverting the zoom levels in your answer?

Comment: Try zoom_range=[1, 2], fill_mode='constant', cval=0

Comment: Why do you have to train it with the 2.5x2.5 patches?

Comment: Because the dataset containing these objects is bigger, and I have only 90 5x5 cm^2 objects images to test. I will try your idea and return to you soon! thanks!

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work either (I got the same 50% accuracy). Maybe because the object is too small and zooming it out will create black pixels not present in the testing set. I believe that the inverse could work (using 5x5cm^2 objects to test, but I dont have a representative dataset of such objects to train). Thanks anyway.

Comment: So you have 2 classes... Which ones?